# Do we share the same name?

Tags: riddle

I am a name for many people,
I am tangible, but not quite so.
give me a kiss, my rival,
You might find the answer laughable.

Comment: hope its not "Baldy" or "Hairy" ;-)

Comment: Is the answer Alex?

Comment: Nope it's not the answer, but I can say you're getting there

Comment: Was that in response to Moose or kanchirk?

Comment: My bad, i didn't catch that.  It's a response to Kanchirk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is probably

> Ass(hole)

I am a name for many people:

> That is most certainly a frequently used insult.

I am tangible, but not quite so:

> Well, one cannot touch a hole technically. But one can touch an ass (probably shouldn't though).

Give me a kiss, my rival:

> We all know the old saying: "Kiss my ass!"

You might find the answer laughable:

> This is sure not a classical answer for a riddle ;)

Comment: So is the answer ass or asshole?

Comment: God, that's brilliant! I would offer you a bounty, but getting rep for going on about arseholes is surely reward enough ;-)

Answer (score 2):

> Bill or Will(iam)?

1. it's a name.
2. a bill is tangible, but one's will may not be?
3. one's will can go against what's best for them

Comment: Not the answer but good guess.  Didn't quite fit line 3 and 4

Comment: "Willy" fits lines 3 and 4

Comment: but I truly hope Willy didn't fit line 2

Comment: You can touch Willy, but only with permission

Answer (score 1):

Could your name be

> Love?

I am a name for many people,

> Love is popular last name, one of the famous bearers of it being [Courtney Love](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courtney_Love).

I am tangible, but not quite so.

> Love is an intangible emotion, yet Rod Stewart claims to be able to ['Touch Love'](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Love_Touch).

give me a kiss, my rival,

> This could be a reference to the song ['Love Your Enemies'](http://lyrics.wikia.com/Smiley_Kids:Love_Your_Enemies) by Smiley Kids.

You might find the answer laughable.

> The song ['Funny How Love Is'](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen_II) by Queen could be the link here.

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for but i'ts good to know some new songs